# Infinitesimal generator why $\lim\limits_{s\to 0}P_t\left(\frac{P_sf-f}{s}\right)=P_tLf$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(P_t)_{t\geq 0}$ a semi group and $f\in D(L)=\left\{f\in \mathcal C_0\mid \lim\limits_{t\to 0}\frac{P_tf-f}{t}\text{ exist}\right\}$ and $\mathcal C_0$ is the set of continuous function s.t. $\lim\limits_{t\to \infty }f(t)=0$.

Set $$Lf=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{P_t f-f}{t}.$$

Suppose $f\in D(L)$. We have $$\lim_{s\to 0}\frac{P_sP_tf-P_tf}{t}=\lim_{s\to 0}P_t\frac{P_sf-f}{s}=P_tLf.$$

I don't understand the last equality, i.e. why $$\lim_{s\to 0}P_t\frac{P_sf-f}{s}=P_t\lim_{s\to 0}\frac{P_sf-f}{s} \  ?$$

Comment: What are the $P_t$'s? Continuous linear transformations?

Comment: $P_t$ is s.t. $P_0=id$, $P_{t+s}=P_t\circ P_s$ and $\lim_{t\to 0}\|P_tf-f\|=0$ and $\|P_t\|\leq 1$ for a certain norm $\|\cdot \|$, but it's not specified. @Berci